# How to get data of more than one field with GROUP BY of one field in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, syntax-error, laravel-8

I am trying to fetch data with more than one column and apply GROUP BY in the query.
This works perfectly in MySQL but gets an error while I am using it in Laravel.

MySQL:

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id
    ,CONCAT (
        first_name
        ," "
        ,last_name
        ) AS full_name
    ,MAX(messages.created_at) AS message_datetime
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(id)
        FROM messages
        WHERE messages.receiver_id = 46
            AND sender_id = users.id
            AND is_read = "0"
        ) AS unread_message_count
    ,messages.message_type
    ,(
        SELECT messages.message
        FROM messages
        WHERE (
                sender_id = user_id
                AND receiver_id = 46
                )
            OR (
                sender_id = 46
                AND receiver_id = user_id
                )
        ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 1
        ) AS message
    ,DATE_FORMAT(messages.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS message_date
    ,DATE_FORMAT(messages.created_at, "%H:%i:%s") AS message_time
    ,users.online
FROM users
JOIN messages ON (
        sender_id = users.id
        AND receiver_id = 46
        )
    OR (
        sender_id = 46
        AND receiver_id = users.id
        )
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY message_datetime DESC
```

Laravel:

```
$data = DB::select(' SELECT users.id as admin_id, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS full_name, MAX(messages.created_at) as message_datetime, (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM messages WHERE  messages.receiver_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' AND sender_id = users.id AND is_read = "0" ) as unread_message_count, messages.message_type, ( SELECT messages.message FROM messages WHERE ( sender_id = admin_id AND receiver_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' ) OR ( sender_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' AND receiver_id = admin_id ) ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS message, DATE_FORMAT(messages.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as message_date, DATE_FORMAT(messages.created_at, "%H:%i:%s") as message_time, users.online FROM users JOIN messages on ( sender_id = users.id AND receiver_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' ) OR ( sender_id = '.Auth::user()->id.' AND receiver_id = users.id ) GROUP BY admin_id ORDER BY message_datetime DESC ');
```

But after running that, I will get an error of:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'talent_base_staging.users.first_name' isn't in GROUP BY

Because I am using user_id in GROUP BY, it says that I have to add another fileds into GROUP BY also

I don't know how to use it in Laravel

Comment: In SQL any field you use in your SELECT  should also be used in your GROUP BY with only the exception of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, if you have an aggregate function in the SELECT portion of the query, like SUM() for instance, you will be required to put ALL the fields in the SELECT portion that are NOT aggregate functions. Because without them, the database will not know how to do the query, there could be anomalies and they know that and therefore make it not run.

Now, saying that, some databases have a property/setting that allows you to turn that off, so that it doesn't throw an error. And that sometimes you might say have 3 non-aggregate fields in the SELECT from the exact same table, that are unique anyway and not having all three in the GROUP BY will have no affect on the resulting query. But sometimes it will, which is why most databases have "include all non-aggregate fields in a Group By) turned on by default.

For Instance, in the docs for MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/group__AGGREGATE__CHECKS.html